# How to run batch file with special character in the directory name

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, directory, path

how do I write a batch file with a diaeresis in the directory name, it doesn't recognize the path when I run it.

I tried this (the actual path)

```
del "C:\Users\¨PC\Documents\*.db" /s /f /q
```

And this by replacing the `¨` with `?`:

```
del "C:\Users\?PC\Documents\*.db" /s /f /q
```

Comment: what is your code page set to? run from `cmd` the command `chcp`

Comment: Write and save the batch file using the appropriate codepage for your 'special' character. Any reasonably decent text editor should allow you to choose the file encoding. The diaeresis is certainly a valid character in both codepage 850, _(Dec 249; Hex F9)_, and codepage 1252,  _(Dec 168; Hex A8)_. Once it is saved with that codepage, you should be fine to add the following line at the very top of the script, ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 850 1>NUL``` or ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 1252 1>NUL```, and the file should be deleted subject to appropriate permissions.